# how do you select a json array if you know the name as a string?

Tags: javascript, json, string, element

```
{
   "slider1": [
     {
     "title": "titleof",
     "description": "something",
     "coverlink": "images/search-icon.png",
     "download": "link"
     }
   ]
},
```

so the json gets loaded and a for loop uses the json to generate the content.

```
 for (b = 0; b < floorvar; b++) {
        addeles[b].innerHTML = "<img src='"+ jsonLoader[slider][b].coverlink +"'/>"
 }
```

in this case slider = slider1 , how can i use the string that i have (slider1) and get it to do the same as

```
addeles[b].innerHTML = "<img src='"+ jsonLoader.slider1[b].coverlink +"'/>"
```

Note: b is the index of the slider as it will have multiple elements, slider1 is a json array so slider1[0] selects the first element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
 for (b = 0; b < floorvar; b++) {
        addeles[b].innerHTML = "<img src='"+ jsonLoader['slider1'][b].coverlink +"'/>"
 }
```

Comment: i think you might of missed it , b is all the elements inside the array i.e
slider1[0] selects the first element of the array

Comment: yes, jsonLoader = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
i have test it as jsonLoader.slider1[b].coverlink  and that works correctly its just there is multiple sliders so if did that all the sliders end up with the same content. and im passing the id of the slider through the function already so it would be handy if i just used to for this basically

Comment: Edited. Is this what you need?

Comment: you gave me the solution is seemed i overrided the variable slider to an object when it was originally a string... my bad

Answer (score 1):

You can access object properties in two ways:

`objectName.propertyName` or `objectName[propertyName]`

so in your case:

```
addeles[b].innerHTML = "<img src='"+ jsonLoader["slider1"][b].coverlink +"'/>"
```

or to make it dynamic:

```
var string = "slider1";
addeles[b].innerHTML = "<img src='"+ jsonLoader[string][b].coverlink +"'/>"
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp